# Why can't hudson find my new version of the parent pom?

Tags: maven, hudson, pom.xml

Everytime I build an new version of my parent pom and point my child pom to the new parent pom, Hudson can't resolve it.  This occurs when Hudson is in it's parsing pom" phase.

```
Sync complete, took 226 ms
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: myGroup:project-pom for project: myGroup:myChildArtifact:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT for project myGroup:myChildArtifact:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After this it goes on to complain that it cant' locate the project-pom in any remote repositories, and it even lists the nexus group where that project-pom most certainly exists.  I've double checked this many times; it's there, but hudson just can't find it for whatever reason.

Note, this is not MAven failing to locate the parent; Hudson is parsing the pom to build it's own meta-data of inter-job relationships, such as which job should be built after another one builds.  Also note that if this is left on it's own for 10-20 hrs, it usually goes away.  So, I can only assume that Hudson is keeping some cache somewhere that I can't seem to find.

Hudson ver. 1.364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was an internal to hudson.  I've upgraded to a new jenkins, 2.2, and I no longer have the problem.